# Member not implemented using Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute abstract class

Tags: c#, xunit

i`m trying to implement Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute abstract class but for some reason it does not work.

```
public sealed class CustomDataAttribute: Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It says:
Abstract inherited member

'`IEnumerable<object[]> Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute.GetData(System.Reflection.MethodInfo)`'

is not implemented.

Then it clearly is implemented.

This error can be reproduced only in one project, in other projects it works fine. Maybe you had a similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a defect in the newer tooling, it is resolvable by adding a build time reference to `System.Reflection` and `System.Runtime` in the `frameworkAssemblies` section of your `project.json` so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "YourAssemblyUnderTest": "1.0.0-*",
    "xunit":  "2.*" 
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "mscorlib": "",
        "System": "",
        "System.Core": "",
        "System.Web": "",
        "System.Reflection": {
          "type": "build",
          "version": ""
        },
        "System.Runtime": {
          "type": "build",
          "version": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is being tracked on [xUnit Issue #618](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/618) and [#716](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/716) with Axel Heer writing a [good post about it](http://axel.heer.eu/2016/01/15/building-dnx-code-using-pcl-dependencies/), albeit in German.  To summarise Axel's post, apologies if I have mistranslated German is not my first language:

> Creating DotNet Core libraries based upon PCL libraries is not working as smoothly as it did before DotNet Core was introduced.  In certain circumstances Types that are included in dependencies of dependencies are not available, which results in compiler errors such as:
>
> - MyDataAttribute does not implement inherited abstract member DataAttribute.GetData (MethodInfo)'
> - MyDataAttribute.GetData (MethodInfo) ': no suitable method found to override
>
> By referencing `System.Reflection` and `System.Runtime` we are explicitly​ referencing these dependencies​.